# Running into Initramfs screen when trying to boot - Tried all methods - not helping

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, backup

I've been running into initramfs for the past two days, so hadn't been able to Boot my system. I loaded Ubuntu 16.04 Live and assuming that it's a bad superblock problem, followed all steps available on the net, to get rid of it.

After following all steps and listing out all Superblock backups, when I try to restore access, it says the Superblock is unreadable and try with alternate superblock. I have tried all Superblock Backups and all of them are giving the same error.

*Also, I have not been able to access my core volume, as I have only a single partition, as it says that it is encrypted. I've been trying to access it with the Live OS in an attempt to atleast be able to take a back up -
[Snapshot of the attempts with different superblock Backups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afonX.png)

Any help that allows me to atleast get hold of my data would be highly appreciated!!

Cheers!

Comment: If you tried all methods how can we possibly help you? Seriously, avoid posting such things. Now the bad news: It's most likely unrecoverable. An encrypted partition in a failing drive is pretty much gone.

Comment: The "tried all methods" part wasn't supposed to be taken literally, as I was emphasising on the fact that I had taken into account all scenarios of Superblock Backups and given it a good shot. Now that you've pointed it out, it does kinda look out of place- hence altered it!!  Appreciate the quick response!! As for the data, a simple file copy via terminal to an ext hard disk, got rid of the encryption and I finally have my data! Yay! For the Bad Superblock part, I couldn't find anything as you pointed out, so gave up and formatted the volume and reinstalled the OS. Cheers Mate!